# How to use react-bootstrap carousel with gatsby-image?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-bootstrap, gatsby

I'm trying to build a react-bootstrap carousel using gatsby-image because the loading speed with the standard img tag is slow. However, the issue I am facing is that I would like to write a single component for all images in a folder, not for each file like in gatsby-starter-default.
So I'd like the Image component to return an array of images that I could use in a Carousel like `<Image[0] />`. Or to pass relativePath to the component inside Carousel like `<Image(carouselImages/carousel_1.jpeg) />`

See carousel.js (reduced to 2 slides for readability) code below.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import './style.scss'
import { injectIntl, Link, FormattedMessage } from "gatsby-plugin-intl"

import Image1 from 'components/img1'
import Image2 from 'components/img2'

class ControlledCarousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      direction: null,
    }
  }

  handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    this.setState({
      index: selectedIndex,
      direction: e.direction,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { index, direction } = this.state

    return (
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={index}
        direction={direction}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}>

        <Carousel.Item>
          <div className="imgWrapper">
           <Image1 />
          </div>
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <p> some text </p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>

        <Carousel.Item>
          <div className="imgWrapper">
           <Image2 />
          </div>
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <p> some text </p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    )
  }
}
export default ControlledCarousel
```

And an Image component itself:

```js
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const Image = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        placeholderImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "carouselImages/carousel_1.jpg" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 2500) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => <Img fluid={data.placeholderImage.childImageSharp.fluid} />}
  />
)
export default Image
```

Any suggestions on the proper way to make it work together? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: If you know all of the relativePaths for each image, take a look in `components/image.js` of the gatsby-starter-default here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/blob/master/src/components/image.js

Comment: I guess the problem was that I tried to give the relative path to a whole folder, not a specific image.

Comment: So you solved this problem already?

Comment: Not really. I created Image components for each picture and it works, but I would like to use a single component for the entire folder of pictures.

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56440113/5385381 It looks quite similar to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Open a folder inside the src/images, and put all the pictures there, then use the filter in the StaticQuery to search for all the pictures inside that folder.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

export default () => (
 <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
    query {
      allFile(filter: {relativeDirectory: {eq: "carousel"}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(quality: 90) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `} 
  render={data=> (
      <Carousel className="full-width-md d-none d-md-block">
      {data.allFile.edges.map(pic => 
      <Carousel.Item>
          <Img fluid={pic.node.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
      </Carousel.Item>
      )}
  </Carousel>
  )}
    />
);
```