# How do I query multiple images with gatsby-image?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have 16 images that I want to render out onto a website in a grid format.

I'm using the following plugins for this:

- `gatsby-image`
- `gatsby-source-filesystem`
- `gatsby-plugin-sharp`
- `gatsby-transformer-sharp`

I read the documentation and as for as I know, it only demonstrated how to query for one single image.

e.g.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello gatsby-image</h1>
    <Img fixed={data.file.childImageSharp.fixed} />
  </div>
)

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "blog/avatars/kyle-mathews.jpeg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        # Specify the image processing specifications right in the query.
        # Makes it trivial to update as your page's design changes.
        fixed(width: 125, height: 125) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

But how would I go about this if I had 16 images? Writing 16 separate queries seem rather cumbersome and would be difficult to read in the future.

I saw this code in the docs referencing multiple images, but I have trouble trying to access the images themselves.

e.g.

```
export const squareImage = graphql`
  fragment squareImage on File {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
`

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    image1: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/image1.jpg" }) {
      ...squareImage
    }

    image2: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/image2.jpg" }) {
      ...squareImage
    }

    image3: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/image3.jpg" }) {
      ...squareImage
    }
  }
`
```

My folder structure is as follows:

---package.json

---src

------images

---------the 16 images

------pages

---------the page where I want to render the 16 images in

etc.

Thank you.

Comment: The answer provided didn't explain how to use the code given in the example. I haven't yet figured out how to import image1, image2 and image3. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @R3N0, "image1:", "image2:", etc. are aliases, so you would refer to them as `data.image1.childImageSharp...`, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having a poke around in GraphiQL should help you, especially the Explorer. Although remember that Gatsby fragments won't work in GraphiQL.

```
{
  allImageSharp {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        fluid(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the above should be equal to something like the following query which *will* work in GraphiQL

```
{
  allImageSharp {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        fluid(maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 200) {
          src
          srcSet
          base64
          aspectRatio
          originalImg
          sizes        
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then your component can use this same query and render the results like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const imgGridStyle = {
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(auto-fill, 200px)`
};

export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello gatsby-image</h1>
    <div style={imgGridStyle}>
      {data.allImageSharp.edges.map(edge => 
        <Img fluid={edge.node.fluid} />
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
)

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allImageSharp {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          fluid(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

You can easily loop over the resulting array of imageSharp nodes returned from the query in `data.allImageSharp.edges.map`. Then pass each node's `fluid` property, as the `fluid` prop to `gatsby-image`.

Note: This renders *every* imageSharp node in your project, which may or may not be what you want to achieve.

---

To filter the query by folder name, you could adjust the query like this:

```
{
  allImageSharp(filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/(myFolder)/"  }}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        fluid(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Have a look at the [gatsby graphql reference for filter](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#filter) as to how you might perform other kinds of filters on the query.

Comment: Beautiful solution, worked perfectly! Thank you. I would like to ask a follow up. Since fluid images automatically fill up the container's width, how do I make sure `maxWidth` works for fluid images so that when it's width is smaller than its containers, the width is retained.

Comment: I made a small edit to the css of the grid container. But basically, you just need  css to somehow constrain each `<Img />` to have a max-width of 200px. There are numerous ways to do this in CSS (but they're probably outside the scope of this question), so feel free to ask another question and link me to it here.

Comment: Awesome, you are right. Adding additional CSS styles that match with the query's styles works. Thank you. It seems like even without using `CSS Grid`, `gatsby-image` already has `flex-wrap` for responsive design? I tested it with fixed images.

Comment: I think they are set to `display: inline-block;`, just like a regular html `<img>`

Comment: Oh really? Cool.

Comment: With this solution, how do you specify the path to the folder with images? Like for example, for a single image there is `image1: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/image1.jpg" })`

Comment: Take a look at the gatsby graphql docs for filtering - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#filter

Comment: Great solution, resolved my issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66405411/gatsby-graphql-regex-query-multiple-images/66411890#66411890

Answer (score 10):

**From Gatsby v3** you just need to use the ***gatsby-plugin-image*** plugin, which provides automatic image optimizations

```
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
export function Dino() {
  return (
    <StaticImage
      src="../images/dino.png"
      alt="A dinosaur"
      placeholder="blurred"
      layout="fixed"
      width={200}
      height={200}
    />
  )
}
```

More information:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/using-gatsby-plugin-image

**Gatsby v2:**

The easiest way is to create an image provider:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

const Image = ({ fileName, alt, style }) => {
  const { allImageSharp } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allImageSharp {
        nodes {
          fluid(maxWidth: 1600) {
            originalName
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const fluid = allImageSharp.nodes.find(n => n.fluid.originalName === fileName)
    .fluid

  return (
    <figure>
      <Img fluid={fluid} alt={alt} style={style} />
    </figure>
  )
}

export default Image;
```

And then, after importing, easily insert the image which you need:

```
<Image fileName="yourImage.jpg" style={{ width: '100%' }} alt="" />
```

Comment: It works, but the bundle size... Can we improve this somehow? i know there are no arguements like `${name}` allowed in static queries.

Comment: Do we have any alternative way just to query using variable inside graghql query

Answer (score 5):

Despite the situation in currently asked question, where all of 16 images are inside the images folder which is then easy to just run a query to fetch all possible images. Like this (accepted answer):

```
{
  allImageSharp {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        fluid(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in most cases you'd like to have subfolders inside the images folder for arranging images according to requirement. (At least that was my case).

So in that case: (where you have images inside a subfolder let's say **beach** inside **images** you can follow this approach)

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allFile(filter: { relativeDirectory: { eq: "beach" } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

This is a small [egghead clip](https://egghead.io/lessons/gatsby-add-multiple-images-from-a-directory-with-gatsby-image) if you want to see in video.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example with TypeScript and SVG support:

Update **gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/images`,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Create **Image** Component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';

interface IProps {
  name: string;
  alt: string;
  className?: string;
}

const Image: FC<IProps> = ({ name, alt, className }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query AllImages {
        allImagesWithoutSVGExtension: allFile(
          filter: {
            sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" }
            extension: { regex: "/jpeg|jpg|png|gif/" }
          }
        ) {
          nodes {
            publicURL
            extension
            sharp: childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                originalName
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
              }
            }
          }
        }
        allImagesWithSVGExtension: allFile(
          filter: {
            sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" }
            extension: { eq: "svg" }
          }
        ) {
          nodes {
            publicURL
            extension
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={({ allImagesWithoutSVGExtension, allImagesWithSVGExtension }) => {
      const isNameWithSVGExtension = name.indexOf('svg') !== -1;

      const renderImageWithSVGExtension = () => {
        const image = allImagesWithSVGExtension.nodes.find(
          ({ publicURL }) => publicURL && publicURL.indexOf(name) !== -1
        );
        return image ? (
          <img
            className={className}
            src={image.publicURL}
            alt={alt}
            width={100}
            height={100}
          />
        ) : null;
      };

      const renderImageWithoutSVGExtension = () => {
        const image = allImagesWithoutSVGExtension.nodes.find(
          ({ publicURL }) => publicURL && publicURL.indexOf(name) !== -1
        );
        return image && image.sharp && image.sharp.fluid ? (
          <Img className={className} fluid={image.sharp.fluid} alt={alt} />
        ) : null;
      };

      return isNameWithSVGExtension
        ? renderImageWithSVGExtension()
        : renderImageWithoutSVGExtension();
    }}
  />
);

export { Image };
```

Use **Image** component as

```
<Image name="logo.svg" alt="compony logo" />
or
<Image name="logo.png" alt="compony logo" />
```